# Javascript implementation of Event Aggregator pattern

Tags: javascript, events, design-patterns

So I have done a lot of research and for some reason I can't find an implementation of the Event Aggregator pattern in Javascript. In fact, the only language that's always used is C# and there's always generics being used. It's a very useful pattern so I fail to realize why it only seems to be 'meant' for .NET. I was hoping that someone would be able to provide an implementation in Javascript or at the very least Java and NOT C# (I've seen enough of that). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to:

1. Get one on the many general purpose publish/subscribe libraries that are implemented and ready to use.  ie https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS (or roll your own - it ain't that hard)
2. Instantiate your event source objects, implement publishing of events.
3. Instantiate your aggregator, make it subscribe to your source objects, and offer publishing of received events.
4. Instantiate your target objects, make them subscribe to your aggregator.

In Javascript the Event Aggregator pattern does not need its own implementation. It is just an object that subscribes to multiple publishers and also publishes to multiple subscribers.

Since there are no type checking or interfaces anything of that sort, you dont need the pattern implemented before you use it, it is just a trivial exercise in pub/sub, which is probably why you can't find it anywhere as an "abstract" implementation.

Look into redux if you want to see something reusable that solves problems in the same domain as the event aggregator pattern, but offers a lot more.